# Is food free in Duronto sleeper?

Tags: trains, india, food-and-drink, indian-railways, irctc

Is food free when traveling in Duronto sleeper class? I know that in 3rd tier, 2nd tier and 1st tier, food is free. But in Sealdah Puri Duronto, Howrah Delhi Duronto, is food free of cost? Is food included in the fare structure? Or does one need to pay extra?

Comment: IRCTC is now offering [e-catering](https://www.ecatering.irctc.co.in/) exclusively for passengers travelling in trains. Please refer [FAQs](https://www.ecatering.irctc.co.in/faq) about IRCTC e-catering.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Food is served for free inside all coaches of Duronto Express. The food charges are already included in your ticket expense. With what I remember from my last booking in a Sleeper Duronto Coach, I was asked the choice of Vegetarian or Non-Vegetarian at the time of booking. In case you missed it, you could just let your coach attendant know about your choice.

IRCTC is now offering [e-catering](https://www.ecatering.irctc.co.in/) exclusively for passengers travelling in trains. Please refer [FAQs](https://www.ecatering.irctc.co.in/faq) about IRCTC e-catering.

Comment: I don't suppose you have any links to authoritative references?

Comment: IRCTC mentions "catering charges Rs 190"(checked on 9 Jan 2017) when you book ticket in sleeper class. So, I think, It should be free. also check this link (page 6) for authorative reference: http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/uploads/directorate/coaching/TAG_2014-15/MenuMeals.pdf