# Does the Nizzamuddin Eraklum Express (train 12284) offer free food for sleeper section travellers?

Tags: trains, food-and-drink, sleeping, indian-railways

I want to travel from Delhi to Manglore with the Nizzamuddin Eruklam Express (12284). Is food offered for free to sleeper section travellers, or do we have to pay for that?

When it reaches Manglore, is it usually on time or delayed by hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is food free in Duronto sleeper?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53164/is-food-free-in-duronto-sleeper)?

Comment: @boroxun looks like a different train

Comment: @JonathanReez Both trains are of Duronto category. So their services will be same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you will be offered food for free in the Nizzamuddin Eruklam Express (12284) as you are already charged in ticket.

For evidence see the screenshot below which I took in the IRCTC website while booking ticket for the same train.

[image]

To answer your second question the train usually reaches Manglore on time.

Comment: Thnx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

They don't offer dinner. They said that as train starts  at 9.35 they will not provide dinner. However from morning they're going to give everything

Comment: Everything? Can you be more specific, maybe add a link?